# Adding a subview and position it with constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, autolayout

I have added a `UIView` using the IB on to the view controller. Let's call it the `redView`.

[image]

Then I have pinned its all four sides using auto layout constraints in code and when I run it, it looks like this as expected.

[image]

Now I want to add a `UILabel` to this view programmatically and position it in the center using auto layout constraints.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var redView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        redView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])


        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Auto Layout Exercise"
        redView.addSubview(label)

        let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let leadingConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let trailingConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
        redView.addConstraints([xCenterConstraint, yCenterConstraint, leadingConstraint1, trailingConstraint1])

    }

}
```

The problem is the label doesn't appear on the `redView`. Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to also set:

```
label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

Otherwise I don't think the constraints will apply to the label.

Comment: And in fact you should be seeing a message in the console to that effect.

Comment: And thank heavens for that message in the console, since it is pretty much guaranteed that I _will_ forget that line of code every time. :)

Comment: Yep, this was the cause. I once tested with the `redView`'s `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` line commented out but it didn't affect the view so I thought this line wasn't mandatory. I guess it is for views you create programmatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

**Note for Swift 2/3**

It has changed to Boolean property: [UIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

Instead of it previously being:

```
label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

It is now:

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 5):

**You need to do this for each UIControl to assign NSConstraints**

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```